# ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.7-slim-bullseye

Tags: docker, docker-compose, debian

When installing [OpenSlides](https://github.com/OpenSlides/OpenSlides/tree/ae5d90a237a2dd527d9c73240ac9eaa00be3168f#more-settings), the following error occurs at the end of the image build:

```
Building openslides/openslides-server:latest...
[+] Building 6.8s (3/3) FINISHED                                                                         docker:default
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                               0.4s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 1.98kB                                                                             0.1s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                  0.5s
 => => transferring context: 142B                                                                                  0.0s
 => ERROR [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.7-slim-bullseye                                  5.6s
------
 > [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/python:3.7-slim-bullseye:
------
Dockerfile:1
--------------------
   1 | >>> FROM python:3.7-slim-bullseye AS base
   2 |
   3 |     ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND noninteractive
--------------------
ERROR: failed to solve: python:3.7-slim-bullseye: failed to do request: Head "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/python/manifests/3.7-slim-bullseye": EOF
```

When I try to download the image manually:
(docker pull python:3.7-slim-bullseye) the following appears after about 20 sec.:

```
Error response from daemon: Head "https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/library/python/manifests/3.7-slim-bullseye": Get "https://auth.docker.io/token?scope=repository%3Alibrary%2Fpython%3Apull&service=registry.docker.io": context deadline exceeded (Client.Timeout exceeded while awaiting headers)
```

What should i do?

Answer (score -1):

I also encountered the same problem,
I guess the docker official may be undergoing maintenance. Wait for a while. If it has not recovered yet, you can consider changing the domain name.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOWp1.png)

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/11107541